# PHP-Layout for Projekt at work

Tags: php

I'm new into this and i want to ask some people with more knowledge than me in this.

I got my website all done for a projekt at work and already can send e-mails with attachments etc.

now i want to put the header of my index into the php page. someone got a solution for it? 
my php so far:

```
<?php   
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                                
    try {
        //Server settings
            $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        #$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                  
            $mail->isSMTP();                                        
            $mail->Host = 'localhost';                              
            $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
            $mail->Port = 25;                                       

        //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('peter@localhost.org', 'Mailer');
            $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"], 'New User');
            $mail->addAddress('peter@localhost.org');


        //Content

            $mail->AltBody = 'test non-HTML';

            $mail->send();
            echo 'E-Mail has been sent';                
    } 
    catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'E-Mail wurde gesendet.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }   

?>
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly what is your problem. i mean you want include the header into your mail ? An edit would be welcome

Comment: this could be wrapped in a separated boilerplate file using `include` before your header starts it's simple nothing more to do if you are only pointing at this

Comment: What do you mean by header of your index?
Do you mean `$mail->addCustomHeader('X-custom-header', 'custom-value');`?

Comment: From what I get from the question, you wish to include a page's content, being the "header" as in a "navigation" and "content" with this? Your question is a tad unclear. If that is the case, just include the file for it.

Comment: If you are present in the question, please respond to the comments. Otherwise, you stand to lose your present audience and if you left the question only to return at a later date, then nobody will know what you're asking and you won't get the solution you are looking to get. I have voted to close the question as unclear and have now left the question, good luck.

Comment: sorry for my bad english ^^ what i meant was to put the header to the page that comes up after i hit the submit button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if totaly understand you...

Do you want to include your index header in the mail body, if so you can add this to your code:

```
$html = file_get_contents('your_header.html'); 

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->MsgHTML($html);
```

Or do you want to include you index header to your php page? you can do that by simply putting `include('your_header.html')` in the begining of the php file.

PHPMailer documentation: [here](http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_msgHTML)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need is to integrate the HTML header of your website in the email header ?

So try this :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                                
try {

    //Server and e-mail settings
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        #$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;                                  
        $mail->isSMTP();                                        
        $mail->Host = 'localhost';                              
        $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
        $mail->Port = 25;    

        $mail->IsHTML(true);                                 

    //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('peter@localhost.org', 'Mailer');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST["email"], 'New User');
        $mail->addAddress('peter@localhost.org');

   //HTML header 
        ob_start();
            ?>Your html content here with body, divs, ...<?php
        $header = ob_get_flush();

    //Content
        $content = "<div>test HTML</div>";

    //Prepare & send
        $mail->Body = $header . $content;
        $mail->AltBody = 'test non-HTML';

        $mail->send();
        echo 'E-Mail has been sent';
} 

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'E-Mail wurde gesendet.<br>Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

mail header example:

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

refer:http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: he actually use PHP mailer so he'll don't use the mail function directly

Comment: yep, this is irrelevant

Comment: with phpmailer or mail functionality headers will be similar. for phpmailer will user $mail->header here it is $headers. how it is irrelevant ?

Comment: He's using the PHPMailer API so better stick with it if you provide an answer